# Native debugging error

Tags: visual-studio, windows-runtime, uwp

If I try to deploy and debug my windows 10 mobile app, the debugging stopped with error:
[image]

It only happens when I set Native debugging. Managed debugging doesn't cause such error.

Comment: This error seems more related to your environment. Have you tested in other devices? Besides, here is [a similar case](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2f539ccf-17ae-465a-9784-cda21e40a1a7/error-when-deploying-windows-10-uwp-app-to-phone?forum=wpdevelop) might be helpful.

Comment: Yes, I tried. Its not working. I think, it causes msvsmon.exe. Its remote debugger on phone.

Answer (score 0):

It is stated [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/07/29/debugging-net-native-windows-universal-apps/) that .NET Native debug engine has some capability differences from normal .NET debugging. Furthermore, it is recommended to debug a non-optimized code:

> These optimizations will have a significant impact on the debugging experience including unpredictable stepping and breakpoint behavior (due to code inlining) and the inability to inspect most variables due to memory optimizations.

Although this was not your presented case, it still pushes further to the following practical solution:

> This means you will want to debug a non-optimized .NET Native build. This fastest way to do this is simply to disable optimizations.

[Source](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/07/29/debugging-net-native-windows-universal-apps/)